# Best way to represent list with image(using url) in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I want to create List View. In this List View, I will have following fields.

```
StackPanel
1- Image with 300 x 400 size
2- Text-Label Controls
```

1 Screen will hardly cover 1 and Half ViewCell.

Images will have ImageURL. I want to load image smoothly. I also want to make smooth scroll up/down with image appearing.

Can anybody please suggest me which control I should use?

If List View, which CacheStrategy I should use?

Note: For one of such functionality, I had used List View with default CacheStrategy. In that, I just faced 1 major problem of image appearing. When page initialize first time, it show image properly. But as soon as I scroll down or scroll up, image disappear or misplace. In that case, I had suffered a lot and removed image finally.

Please suggest appropriate way for above functionality.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the listview, you should definitely use `RecycleElement` as the `CachingStrategy`. See here https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ListViewCachingStrategy/#Remarks

And because the images are URLs, you can use [FFImageLoading](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.FFImageLoading/). It will fade-in the image after it is downloaded (as opposed to appearing instantly after downloaded), and you can even specify a placeholder image to use while the image is being downloaded.

Comment: I have tried both. I think FFImageLoading is much more smoother and faster than Image control.